# Modules in Project Explorer are not grouped anymore into modules, classes and forms

Tags: excel, vba, project-explorer

Modules in MS Office Project Explorer have always been grouped into forms, modules and classes, with "pluses" that allow to collapse or expand the groups. Either I have pressed some random hotkey, or the latest MS Office update messed it up, BUT now all my modules are just a list sorted by name (see  the screenshot). It's the same in all Office programs. What has happened, and is there a remedy to this? I want my groups back :-(

[image]

I looked through all settings in VBA Editor, but I never found anything related to the problem.

Comment: Just click with the right click on any module and click on the "Alternate folders" or whatever is called in the english version. The one with a folder icon.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Surprisingly, have never even noticed it in 21 years of VBA coding! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Toggle Folders</kbd> button in your Project Explorer:

[image]

Alternatively use the <kbd>Toggle Folders</kbd> button in the context menu of the Project Explorer.